# Is there a way to define a custom sprite for a specific item or block using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for a way to implement custom item sprites in my vanilla world.  Is there a way to, say, add a custom sprite to a resource pack and then call that sprite with a command block?  I want to be able to have custom items, armor, and blocks that don't look like the generic versions from the resource pack.

Hopefully there is a way to do this with command blocks, perhaps by defining some data tag I'm not aware of when doing a /give command?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

in versions before 1.8.3 I know that you could make armourstands with custom playerheads just larger than a block. in the newest versions, howerver, custom playerheads do not work, I wouldnt use new versions for command blocks for several other reasons, too, such as rendomized dispensers.

Comment: Player heads work just fine. It was a huge misconception that they did not; people were abusing a specific security issue and that issue was fixed. You can upload a custom skin, create a player head from that skin, and change your skin back.